# How can I reuse Authlogic's password encryption functionality in a Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, module, authlogic

In my Rails app, I periodically require the user to re-enter their password after a certain amount of inactivity--like with sudo on Linux. My app uses Authlogic for authentication and handling password storage and encryption.

I need some method to encrypt the password the user enters using the exact same encryption scheme Authlogic uses to encrypt passwords when it verifies passwords during authentication.  I need to 1) encrypt the password the user enters and 2) do a string comparison between this encryption and the encrypted password stored in the database for the user.

Where should I put the method to perform this encryption? Here are some ideas:

Idea 1 (in a new, custom module)

```
module PasswordCryption
  include Authlogic::ActsAsAuthentic::Password

  encrypt_password(password)

  end
end
```

Idea 2 (in the User model)

```
class User
  acts_as_authentic <---- makes Authlogic password encryption functionality available

  encrypt_password(password)

  end
end
```

Comment: why not logout the user after a certain time and then let the user login using authlogic standard login mechanism?

Comment: Did you find an answer to this? I'm also trying to compare a string with a stored password, using jQuery Validation plugin to validate a login.

Answer (score 1):

Authlogic uses the SHA512 encryption by default. The clue is that authlogic repeated the hexdigest function 20 times. This will solve your problem:

```
digest = [raw_password, password_salt].join('')
crypted_password = 20.times { digest = Digest::SHA512.hexdigest(digest) }
```